# Cygwin bash script goes wrong on pipes when sourced

Tags: bash, cygwin, pipe, 64-bit

I have installed Cygwin x64 on Windows 7, with no changes to defaults. I copied the home environment from another PC on which Cygwin had been working happily for years. This time when logging in (bash) a near endless stream of errors occurs, which I have narrowed down to the following problem. This very small script behaves differently when invoked normally as opposed to sourced.

```
echo test
echo test | cat
echo t`echo es`t
echo t`echo es | cat`t
echo t$(echo es)t
echo t$(echo es | cat)t
```

Output of script invoked normally:

```
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

Output of script when sourced:

```
test
test
test
tt
test
tt
```

Pipes within code to be executed as sub-shells are apparently broken on my installation.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a magic setting I am not aware of that will suddenly make everything OK again?

Comment: What versions of `bash` are you using?  I cannot recreate the results.  Even when sourcing I get the full `test` output for each line.  Saving it in `t.sh` and running `./t.sh` or `source t.sh` both work for me.

Comment: Found something to do with buffering in pipes. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe
Possibly related?

Comment: Are you sure your login shell is `bash`? sourcing a script runs it in the same shell as it's run from, so if that's some different shell it might explain the weird behavior.

Comment: @KindStranger Buffering should just delay when `cat` produces output; it shouldn't cause a *loss* of output as seen here.

Comment: It almost looks like a carriage return issue, except I would expect output like `tts`, not `tt`.

Comment: What does `echo "t$(echo es | cat)t"` produce? (Having no idea what the problem is, I don't expect it to fix the problem, but in general you should be quoting a command substitution anyway.)

Comment: You may reinstall Cygwin on second machine, what do you mean by copying home environment ?

Comment: $() implemented in new versions of bash, it could be that your cygwin runs older version.

Comment: @EricRenouf: bash -- version yields: 4.4.12(3)

Comment: @GordonDavisson: echo $0 says: -bash

Comment: @chepner: No cr/lf issue (this time!). Here's the top two lines from od -a:  
`0000000   #  sp   e   c   h   o  sp   t   e   s   t  nl   #  sp   e   c  
0000020   h   o  sp   t   e   s   t  sp   |  sp   c   a   t  nl   #  sp`

Comment: @Tamar If by "new versions of `bash`", you mean something released since 1997, maybe.  Support for `$(...)` was already present in `bash` 2.0, and was likely supported earlier than that.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: I did a clean install, then copied the older content of /home/<user> (from the other PC) over this one.

Comment: @vandoornw That is weird, and suggests this is definitely specific to Cygwin, which I don't really know anything about.

Comment: @chepner: sorry about the wrong information given earlier (now deleted). Here's what happens: when I call the script with your line (with the double quotes, added as #7) by sourcing it, the expected happens: it fails in the same way.

However, when I call it without sourcing it (subshell) that 7th line shows the same error as when sourced! (so: tt). The other six are, of course, unchanged.

I'm going slightly mad.

Comment: I think it must be something specific within your script, even with cygwin bash 4.4.12(3) on Win 7 I cannot recreate your results copying and pasting your example code from the question.  I see `test` for every line of output

Comment: Added a new user, ran the same script, still the same problem in a totally fresh, unmodified account.

Now going for the nuclear option: zapping all of the cygwin installation, and retrying with the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, it was definitely something in the installation, and something I'm not going to look into any further. I've installed the 32-bit version of Cygwin instead of the 64-bit one, and the script now does exactly what was expected. Problem not solved, but circumvented.

Thanks to all who had a look in!